# What is the meaning of ‘ broke’ here?

Tags: transitive-verbs

What is the meaning of ‘broken‘ in this phrase

‘but all he could learn was that Mr Abel had himself broken the intelligence to his mother,’

> While he was thus engaged, Kit made some anxious inquiries about his employers, and whether they had expressed any opinion concerning him; but all he could learn was that Mr Abel had himself broken the intelligence to his mother, with great kindness and delicacy, late on the previous night, but had himself expressed no opinion of his innocence or guilt.

Comment: I guess this is from _The Old Curiosity Shop_, but you really should give the source of literary quotations you are asking about.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with Old English.

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of *break* is to make known:

> To make known, as news: break a story.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=break

The most common use of this construction is in television news announcing a breaking story.

So broken here means announced or told.

Comment: Yes , I think so.  and thank you for your fast answer